# Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I get this message whenever I try to flag any post: **"Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!"**. But, this isn't true.

None of my last 6 flags have been declined! All 6 flags are helpful!

Here is my flagging history

```
66  moderator attention flags

3   waiting for review

56  deemed helpful

4   declined

3   disputed
```

Close to **85%** of my flags are **helpful**, and only about 6% of my flags have been declined! But, still I'm not allowed to flag any post.

I would like to know the proper reason for not allowing me to raise any flag.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a newbie mistake on how to report serial downvoting. 
I flagged the serial downvoting posts, and didn't realize that I was only supposed to downvote one and wait. 
Now I can't re-flag the downvoting post as requested after waiting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The critical word there is **recent** flags. Specifically, flags handled in the past 7 days:

[image]

In the past 7 days, you've raised 15 flags. 4 of them have been declined - that's just a bit over 25%. Critically, you flagged [the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file/31331336#31331336) *twice* - both flags were declined. Generally, you don't want to do that unless you're adding a significant amount of useful information the second time (for instance, by selecting "in need of moderator intervention" and explaining in detail what is wrong).

The purpose of this block is just to give you a chance to reflect on the reason for your declined flags. By tomorrow, you'll only have 3 flags declined in the past 7 days, and you should be able to flag again.

### See also: [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)

Comment: But, this step should have been taken soon after my 4 flags were declined. But, instead I was allowed to flag further and those flags turned out to be useful and now I am not allowed to flag. I feel it's a bit strange!

Comment: Side-effect of the sliding window; a day earlier, there were enough helpful flags in the past 7 days to avoid the ban (although you should've seen a warning). As those got older, the makeup of the last 7 days changed.