# Using duplicate report to increase the answer votes. What should we do?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today, I noticed an odd behavior. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37685751/3328979) and someone reported it as duplicate. The question was completely different but the main cause of the issue was same.

When I checked the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665439/3328979) of the duplicate, I noticed that it is provided by the duplicate reporter. Surprisingly I noticed that his answer refers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29444009/3328979) which is exact duplicate of my question but he preferred to report my question as duplicate of the wrong one because his answer is marked as accepted there.

I think we should have a mechanism to prevent this kind of wrong dupe reports. Maybe setting a reputation penalty for wrong duplicate reports? Any ideas about this issue and how to prevent it?

Comment: [There is already a penalty.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304048/too-many-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-declined-please-review-them-instead-of)

Comment: We want more people to find duplicates, if you penalise the few that do for making mistakes which they are bound to now and again nobody will bother.

Comment: If anybody needs to be "penalized" then surely it is questioners that don't research their question and add duplicates.  They waste an enormous amount of energy.

Comment: @HansPassant, that is completely true, but you missed the main point of this question. Some persons are misusing duplicate report to link questions to their accepted answer. We should prevent it.

Comment: @arashsoft yeah maybe. Hans point is that people posting duplicates are misusing the site... Anyway.

Comment: @Patrice, I do not believe so. Posting duplicates *without doing enough research* is misusing the site. It is possible that someone search for a long time and still do not find the question.

Comment: @Hans, who needs to be penalized first: the questioners who don't research and post duplicates, or the hi-rep users who **answer** them even though they know there are a bazillion dupes already? *(Of course I'm not referring to you. Or myself, for that matter.)*

Comment: @Frédéric - I find the entire concept rather medieval.  Google "should you spank your child".  Quoting the top hit: "... more likely than the non-spanked to be defiant, demand immediate satisfaction of their wants and needs, become frustrated easily, have temper tantrums and lash out physically against other people or animals".  Yeah, we see that :)

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything wrong with an answerer pointing out duplicates to one of their own answers.  The whole point of duplicate closure is to reuse answers for questions that are the same.  In this regard, the answerer of the target question is quite qualified at recognizing when the questions are the same.  After all, they answered the first one successfully, so they should be able to identify new duplicates.

In fact, this is the logic behind giving gold tag badge users [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/280467) privileges.  Since they wrote at least 200 answers with decent scores, they have a very good idea which questions have been answered in their tags.  And with their vast personal contributions, it's quite likely that the targets they point to will be answers they wrote.

Comment: I understand your point of view. But, his report is not a valid duplicate. His reference in the accepted answer is the correct duplicate.

Comment: @Arashsoft while the original target wasn't ideal, it did actually answer your question.  The other target is obviously better, but I wouldn't say that the first duplicate vote was malicious or sketchy.  People naturally remember their own stuff better than other stuff.